# Facing an "Internal Compiler Error" when trying to compile with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web, dll

In an asp.net webforms app, no matter how do we try to add the rqueired reference, we are still getting the following errors, when using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0584  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol 'Settings'  1_App_Code  C:\Users\BarExpo\source\Rms\Rms\RmsNew\RMS\RMS\App_Code\Settings.cs 19  Active
Error   CS0584  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'CODEGEN' symbol 'Settings.AddFile(System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload, string, string)'    1_App_Code  C:\Users\BarExpo\source\Rms\Rms\RmsNew\RMS\RMS\App_Code\Settings.cs 593 Active
Error   CS0584  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'COMPILE' symbol 'Settings.AddFile(System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload, string, string)'    1_App_Code  C:\Users\BarExpo\source\Rms\Rms\RmsNew\RMS\RMS\App_Code\Settings.cs 593 Active
Error   CS0585  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'CODEGEN'    1_App_Code  C:\Users\BarExpo\source\Rms\Rms\RmsNew\RMS\RMS\App_Code\Settings.cs 599 Active
Error   CS0585  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'CODEGEN'    1_App_Code  C:\Users\BarExpo\source\Rms\Rms\RmsNew\RMS\RMS\App_Code\Settings.cs 610 Active
Error   CS0585  Internal Compiler Error: stage 'CODEGEN'    1_App_Code  C:\Users\BarExpo\source\Rms\Rms\RmsNew\RMS\RMS\App_Code\Settings.cs 622 Active
```

Seems that the main issue is accures in the following code:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(tempPath);
    wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ClientFolderFiles + fileName),             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
    wordDocument.Close();
```

Any solutions/explanation for the Error?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb2SW.png)

We have tried to add the required reference in a lot of ways,
tried with few version of the dll, and also to rebuild the solution in few workspaces.

Comment: If you going to use office interop assemblies, then you ALSO need to install a valid working copy of office, or at the very least a valid working copy of Word. And you ALSO must ensure that the copy of word you install on that computer also matches the bit size of your project settings (don't use ANY Cpu anymore, but force project to x86 or x64 bits). So, not sure what about some .dll, but at the end of the day, you need a valid working copy of Word installed on that computer, and in the case of web servers, such a setup is not recommended, nor supported.

Comment: This is because the compiler itself encountered problems during the compilation process. These errors are usually not caused directly by the code, but by problems with the compiler or build environment. You can try reinstalling the Office main interop assembly